# Javascript comma operator

Tags: javascript, comma-operator

When combining assignment with comma (something that you shouldn't do, probably), how does javascript determine which value is assigned? Consider these two snippets:

```
function nl(x) { document.write(x + "<br>"); }
var i = 0;
nl(i+=1, i+=1, i+=1, i+=1);
nl(i);
```

And:

```
function nl(x) { document.write(x + "<br>"); }
var i = 0;
nl((i+=1, i+=1, i+=1, i+=1));
nl(i);
```

The first outputs

```
1
4
```

while the second outputs

```
4
4
```

What are the parentheses doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was confusing two things, here. The first call to 'nl' is a function call with four arguments. The second is the evaluation of the comma into one argument.

So, the answer: the value of a list of expressions separated by ',' is the [value of the last expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: Well, at least you have a nice little "what does this code do" question now. :)