# Multiple counters in Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Before i tear my hair out and go down the wrong path in terms of debugging. Can someone confirm that this code will do as intended. Ie. animate 5 divs to different positions:

```
var i, j, k;
$('#menuButton').click(function(){
    for (i=1; j=0; k=150; i<=5; i++; j+=30; k-=30){
        $('.spinner #item' + i).animate({
            left: '+=' + j,
            bottom: '+=' + k
          }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    }
});
```

When i click the `#menuButton`, nothing happens and I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; on the 'for()' line...

Comment: A for loop only takes three expressions. You probably want `,` between variable assignments. The `;` are for separating the initial assignment, condition, and the expression to run after each iteration.

Comment: Why increment three different variables rather than increment one and multiply by it for the other values? http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7fkx7/2/

Comment: @Jasper I like this a lot but it doesnt quite fit my requirements, i need the values to start at the ones i defined...

Comment: @benhowdle89 Gotcha. I see how this syntax is easy to use in that case. But you *can* add the initial value to each of the multiplications: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7fkx7/3/. `bottom : '+=' + (i * -30 + 150)`. It's like they teach you in algebra in High School for the equation of a line :)... `ax+c` (where `c` is your constant and `a` is your slope/rate)

Comment: @Jasper Fantastic!!! Out of interest, how would i apply a slightly more curved effect, rather than just in one line...

Comment: @benhowdle89 Here's a formula for a curved line: `ax^n + c` (`30x^0.9 + 150`) where `a` is your slope/rate, `n` is your exponential multiplier, and `c` is your constant (Y-intercept). And an example with a small amount of curve: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7fkx7/4/. Here is an example with more curve: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7fkx7/5/

Comment: @benhowdle89 OK, I'm having fun with this, here's an example of using the `Math.sin()` function to place DOM elements on a sin-curved-path: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7fkx7/6/

Comment: @Jasper You sir, blow my mind. I'm doing this for a demo post, i will credit you accordingly : )

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You've got some semicolons where you want commas:

```
for (i=1, j=0, k=150; i<=5; i++, j+=30, k-=30) { /* do work */ }
```

You should only have three "statements" inside your `for`

```
for( [init]; [test]; [increments]) { [block] }
```

To do multiple `[inits]` or `[increments]` you have to use the sometimes [magical, but oft forgotten, comma operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/)

Answer (score 16):

too much semicolons there

```
for (i=1; j=0; k=150; i<=5; i++; j+=30; k-=30){
```

should be

```
for (i=1, j=0, k=150; i<=5; i++, j+=30, k-=30){
```

Answer (score 2):

You made gramatical errors in your code that you could have easily spotted had you used [static code analysis tools such as the lovely JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/reports/76017).

In addition, you should further understand the use of the [comma operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-comma-operator) in JavaScript, our site has [a few answers on it already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502138/javascript-comma-operator).