# Javascript: enumerate skews and rotations with multiple loop increments

Tags: javascript, loops

This question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348792/multiple-counters-in-javascript-for-loop) that I think it's answer doesn't cover my problem. I have the following:

```
var props = ['skew','rotate'], 
    axis = ['X','Y','Z'];

for (var p=0, a=0; p<2, a<3; p++, a++){
    console.log(props[p]+axis[a])
}
```

Why sometimes this logs `undefinedX`?

UPDATE: the log should write `rotateX rotateY rotateZ skewX skewY skewZ`.

Comment: `p<2, a<3` is only going to use the comparison to `a`. You need `&&` to have both included in the condition.

Comment: You mean `for (var p=0, a=0; p<2 && a<3; p++, a++){}` ?

Comment: Yes, if you intend for the loop to continue only as long as both are true. I don't know what result you expect.

Comment: Yes I corrected the question result. Thanks

Comment: What's the end result you want to get? If done properly, this will only iterate up to `2`,so there is no need for two loop variables.

Comment: why not just use an inner and outer loop?

Comment: @MoisheLipsker that is what I had before, I found a glitch and thought this may be the reason. I had to try another idea.

Comment: FYI, what you seem to be looking for is the [**Cartesian product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inner and outer loop to enumerate all combinations

```js
var props = ['skew','rotate']
,   axis = ['X','Y','Z']
,   result = '';

for(prop = 0; prop < props.length; prop ++) {
    for(dir = 0; dir < axis.length; dir ++) {
        result += props[prop] + axis[dir] + '<br/>';
    }
}
document.write(result);
```

The problem with using a single loop for two arrays of different sizes is that both variables are incremented as long as code hasn't reached end of one array.

Now that could be fixed by checking in the loop and capping the index in the array at length - 1 of the array.

However, a bigger problem in using this approach is that you aren't actually concatenating each value in the first array to each variable in the second array. You are concatenating each value from first array at a certain position to the corresponding value from second array at same position.

Comment: I see you insist on the idea, you have any intel that a `for (var p=0, a=0; p<2 && a<3; p++, a++){}` wouldn't work in legacy browsers? Or why insist? Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @thednp: the two solutions produce very different results. But we still don't know what *you* want.

Comment: well `p<2 && a<3` means as long as both are less, increment `p` and `a` and then go to next iteration of for loop. The problem with that here is that`props` and `axis` aren't the same size.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: I don't do `for .. in` for arrays ofc. the && does some work but I will get back to for inside for.

Comment: @thednp: again, both solutions produce different results. The single for loop in your example would produce "skewX", "rotateY". The nested for loop produces "skewX", "skewY", "skewZ", "rotateX", "rotateY", "rotateZ". What do you want?

Comment: Exactly that @FelixKling. Thank you for explaining so clear now I understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @thednp: What's "that"? Please update your question with the output you want to get.